# Backbone Nesting - General Architecture

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, nested

I've been doing some research and don't see an example for my specific use case.  So general architecture advice/resources would be appreciated.

I'm creating a address book.

- Users create contacts and groups.
- Created contacts live in a general pool.
- Contacts can be associated with multiple groups.
- If a contact is updated, it's updated across all groups.
- If a contact is removed from the general pool, it's removed from all associated groups.

Creating separate collections for the contacts and groups was easy, but now I'm kind of stuck.

It appears that [Backbone-associations](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations) or [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or even [nesting.js](https://gist.github.com/1610397) would provide what I'm looking for.  Looks like Backbone-associations is more performant than Backbone-relational.  Does anybody have experience with any of the plugins?  Is there an easier hand-code solution?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should try to find solution with standard backbone methods and only if you can not - you should take side application.

As for your application - there is a solution. You should store collection of contacts and collection of groups in two different separated collections. Every model in contacts collection should have "link" to its group elements - for example additional field "groups" that just contain its groups models (and if you know, JavaScript operates links when you operate the same object, so it is lightweight)

Having collection of such contacts you can write a special method, that uses this collection sorted by group (implement collection comparator method for this) and returns any useful object for rendering. For example:

```
{"group1": elements_of_group1, ...}
```

And as a side effect when you remove any contact you already have consistent list.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a backbone model representing a group and a collection.  The group could contain an array of contactIds:

```
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "SomeName",
        phone: "1234567890",
        ...
    }
});

var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
       name: "someName",
       contactIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
});

var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact
});
```

If you need to access the details of a contact stored in a given group, you could do something like:

```
contacts.get(id);
```

to return the individual contact's information for a CRUD operation.  You could similarly maintain a collection of groups.